# Computationally predicting small molecule/peptide based on others' binding to target protein

Tags: computational-chemistry, proteins, from-chem-se

Say you have a small molecule or peptide that binds to a protein of interest. I'm interested in predicting the properties of the other type of ligand that might bind in a similar way.

For example:

**A)** peptide binds to target T. I want to computationally predict properties of a small molecule that might bind T in the same way

OR

**B)** small molecule binds to T. I want to computationally predict properties of a peptide that might bind T in the same way

So I have a question: **Is this unfeasible? Or do methods exist to do try to do this *in silico***?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! I've made your question more likely to get an answer by narrowing it down to just one question. If the answer to this question is "no", then the second question is not necessary, and if it's "yes" then you are welcome to ask it as a seaparate question on this site!

Comment: Yes it is feasible and numerous methods exist, with various strengths and weaknesses. See [this article on chemical fingerprinting for small molecules and large molecules such as peptides](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13321-020-00445-4#:~:text=MAP4%20is%20a%20new%20molecular,describe%20and%20search%20chemical%20space.) as a start.

Comment: Normally, you could use QSAR (quantitative structure- activity or property relationships) but you need to have a well tested set in order to obtain the regression models. As you have only two molecules, you could determine the [pharmacophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacophore) of both, and them compare them. The best approach will be done molecular docking and/or molecular dynamic simulation for both compounds.

Comment: In this case, @Camps, QSAR is not a viable option, even with a substantial dataset. QSAR's molecular descriptors are only suitable for small molecules and cannot be applied to peptides. Additionally, if a model is trained on small molecules, it may not be applicable to peptides, which would most likely lie outside the model's applicability domain.
Using a pharmacophore approach appears to be the best option here, however it must be noted that peptides often bind through different mechanisms than small molecules.